# Launching Form B before form A. Why form A don't see user authentication information?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Simple synopsis: I have a program which needs authentication from user to get access or create file with user name and password. I have form A and form B; form A is a main window of my program which have a button pointing to form B, which is log in form. As of right now I must launch form A, and then click a button to go to form B because of necessary log in access to the files. My program is recognizing if person has logged in and it enables buttons that let me create a new file or access already created one (they are disabled by default, and only are enabled if authentication was first successful).

**How can I make form to check for authentication before form A is opened?**

Let me know if I am not clear enough...

Now, I have tried to initialize a form B before form A by doing this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    AuthenticationWindow login = new AuthenticationWindow();
    login.ShowDialog();

    InitializeComponent();
}
```

The problem is that when I do so that my program isn't enabling my buttons after authentication was in place.

I have tried to check for authentication before initializing my form by:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    AuthenticationWindow login = new AuthenticationWindow();
    login.ShowDialog();

    if (storedAuth != null)
    {
        // Making Deleting and Adding possible
        // when file was opened.
        tsmiOpen.Enabled = true;
        tsmiNew.Enabled = true;
    }

    InitializeComponent();
}
```

But still I can't open or create a file. Seems like program isn't checking for authenticated user.

This is my code which enables my buttons after authentication:

```
private void tsmiAuthenticate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AuthenticationWindow authWindow = new AuthenticationWindow();

    authWindow.ShowDialog();
    storedAuth = authWindow.Result;

    if (storedAuth != null)
    {

        tsmiOpen.Enabled = true;
        tsmiNew.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

My shrinked code:

```
namespace Password_Manager
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Form
    {
        private AuthenticateUser storedAuth;
        private HashPhrase hash = new HashPhrase();

        private bool newSelected, openSelected;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            AuthenticationWindow login = new AuthenticationWindow();
            login.ShowDialog();

            if (storedAuth != null)
            {
                // Making Deleting and Adding possible
                // when file was opened.
                tsmiOpen.Enabled = true;
                tsmiNew.Enabled = true;
            }

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void tsmiAuthenticate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AuthenticationWindow authWindow = new AuthenticationWindow();

            // Displaying Authenticate Window.
            // Not allowing switching between forms.
            authWindow.ShowDialog();
            storedAuth = authWindow.Result;


            if (storedAuth != null)
            {
                // Making Deleting and Adding possible
                // when file was opened.
                tsmiOpen.Enabled = true;
                tsmiNew.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        private void tsmiAddEntry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Checking if the file is new or opened.
            // This matter because we need to
            // have appropriate path to the file.
            if (openSelected)
            {
                AddEntryWindow addWindow = new AddEntryWindow
                    (this, storedAuth.UserName, storedAuth.Password, 
                    ofdOpenFile.FileName);

                // Displaying Add Entry Window.
                // Not allowing switching between forms so I am using ShowDialog().
                addWindow.ShowDialog();
            }
            if (newSelected)
            {
                AddEntryWindow addWindow = new AddEntryWindow
                    (this, storedAuth.UserName, storedAuth.Password, 
                    sfdNewFile.FileName);

                // Displaying Add Entry Window.
                // Not allowing switching between 
                // forms so I am using ShowDialog().
                addWindow.ShowDialog();
            }
        }

        private void tsmiDeleteEntry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Checking if the file is new or opened.
            // This matter because we need to
            // have appropriate path to the file.
            if (openSelected)
            {
                // When open file.
                DeleteEntryWindow deleteEntyWindow = new DeleteEntryWindow
                    (this, storedAuth.UserName,
                    storedAuth.Password, ofdOpenFile.FileName);
                deleteEntyWindow.ShowDialog();
            }
            else if (newSelected)
            {
                // When new file.
                DeleteEntryWindow deleteEntyWindow = new DeleteEntryWindow
                    (this, storedAuth.UserName,
                    storedAuth.Password, sfdNewFile.FileName);
                deleteEntyWindow.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your InitializeComponent() code is resetting your buttons' .Enabled properties to false.  The code in this method is the code that is created by the form designer in VS.

Try this...

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AuthenticationWindow login = new AuthenticationWindow();
            login.ShowDialog();
            storedAuth = login.Result;


            if (storedAuth != null)
            {
                // Making Deleting and Adding possible
                // when file was opened.
                tsmiOpen.Enabled = true;
                tsmiNew.Enabled = true;
            }


        }
```

Comment: It still leaves my buttons disabled.

Comment: I doubt it, I'm not sure what's stepping :)

Comment: You don't know how set a breakpoint and step through the code using the F10 and F11 keys?

Comment: I'm not going to lie... I never used it, I just debug it. I have never seen a need for F10/11 keys. I'm kind of new into this.

Comment: Something to investigate, it comes in handy --  and will make the keys feel wanted. In the meantime, try the code I posted -- I edited to actually set the auth value.

Comment: You must be a detective! You nailed it!